# How to ensure an executable script runs upon double clicking it?

Tags: shell, debian

I've written a very simple shell script called script1.sh in whonix:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "here is an example"
```

It is located in /home/user/test. Afterwards I've opened konsole and typed:

```
cd /home/user/test
chmod +x /home/user/script1.sh
```

to make sure it is executable. But if I right-mouse-button click it *>open with >konsole*, it opens the console but does not execute.

Whereas if I, in konsole, type:

```
/home/user/test/script1.sh
```

it does.

What do I have to do/change/add in the shell script to make sure it runs as soon as it is opened?

Comment: This would not be a shell code problem, but more instructing what sounds like KDE (based on the `konsole` command hint) to do what you want. Mac OS X "solves" this problem by running `*.command` files upon clicky; the solution for any other graphical environment will vary depending on that environment.

Answer (score 0):

The rmb open with action usually requires that you supply the file name of the file to execute as a parameter to the program, konsole in this case. Bash is the shell and konsole is a program that runs the shell inside it. In your case when you select your program and ask konsole to run it, kde probably gets konsole the program to run it which obviously fails. What you want instead is to let bash run it. If you just double click the file in explorer, that is exactly what'll happen.

To use the right click method you'll need more settings and plumbing in your explorer. So it's gui dependent. Hope my answer was clear.

Comment: Actually, if I just double click it, it does exactly the same as when I rmb>Open with>open with konsole; Opening konsole with the directory in which the shell script is located, as active directory, but not running the script.   

So I think rather than being dependent on the operating system and how to open the shell script, the problem is that my shellscript is not properly formatted.    


I'm thinking the discrepancy is that I have written it in active commands rather than script executables, but I can't find the right syntax to ensure it actually executes immediatly once it is opened.

Comment: The script just uses the echo command, nothing wrong with it that I can tell. Probably it just executed and you aren't able to see the output fast enough. Try a command that waits for input. Like "read" and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks, I had already tried with calling another script, but it's a good suggestion to eliminate that variable and just incorporating a wait in it :)
So I'm gonna give that a try.

Comment: I was incorrect. It was indeed a environment option. There is another option: "rmb>action>run in konsole" which does run the script. Somehow I did not notice this option initially. 
Now that I know it is possible, I can look for a way to incorporate it to autostart, but that is off-topic on this forum. 
Thanks for thinking with me, and removing the doubt about the correctness of the script :)

Comment: You're welcome. So do I get an upvote now ;) just kidding. Glad you solved your problem

Comment: I always give upvotes, but karma isn't high enough for it to count yet :)